# VideoView bug on Android 7

Tags: android, android-videoview

I'm using VideoView for playing video in my app. In first fragment i have VideoView that hold half of the screen. Tapping on video opens new fragment with fullscreen VideoView. Fragments have totally separate layouts with different instances of VideoView.

Error Case: i start play on first fragment -> tap on video during play -> fullscreen video opened -> i press play button and i see fullscreen video overlapped by video form previous fragment. Does anyone faced this problem?

This bug persist on Android API 24, but on Android N all works perfectly.

Comment: please share your error log

Comment: Need more for this, with no code or screenshot it's impossible to help

Comment: have the same issue with videoView in viewpager. Did you resolve your issue?

Comment: Yeap, i've just used another player, base on texture view. Described behavior in VideoView can not be solved - it ignores layout hierarchy by its nature.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and found the following workaround: Set the height of the video view to 0 when switching away from the fragment. Note that you need to delay the switch by a few milliseconds (100ms worked for me) for this to work:

```
 val layoutParams = videoView.layoutParams
 layoutParams.height = 0
 videoView.layoutParams = layoutParams
 videoView.requestLayout()
 Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed({
     //Switch fragment here
 }, 100L)
```